# SERVER_ADDR undefined index

Tags: php

I am getting an undefined index on my config page and it reads:

> **Notice**:  Undefined index:  SERVER_ADDR in **inc/config
>   .inc.php** on line **3**

Any idea on how I can fix that? I know its warning, but would still like to get at it. I am using it to check for the address whether to use my local or remote config settings.

I am using it in this context:

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1' || $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost') {        

}
```

Comment: Just rely on the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']  because $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] may or may not be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't done so, make sure you're accessing SERVER_ADDR using the $_SERVER array to obtain the value of SERVER_ADDR, which is an element of this array.

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
```

If that doesn't work, it may mean that your server doesn't provide that information.

From [PHP.net](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey Marc,

That is the variable I am using, I will try the other suggestions below. Thanks for your help.

Ryan

Comment: how is this different from what he used in the question?

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is correct, but take note that on Windows IIS 7 (and above, to the best of my knowledge) you must use:

```
$_SERVER['LOCAL_ADDR']
```

instead of

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [`getenv`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php)?

```
getenv('SERVER_ADDR')
```

Comment: +1 `$_SERVER` is a bad idea when you have `getenv()` lying around.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for `$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]` in IIS which is not defined there.

Try `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` instead, it is set always as long as you force `HTTP 1.1`

Comment: I believe that $HTTP_SERVER_VARS is deprecated; $_SERVER should be used instead.

Comment: HTTP_HOST does not provide the IP ADDRESS though.

Answer (score 0):

You can Query your $_SERVER variable like below and investigate the contents for debugging:

```
foreach($_SERVER as $a=>$b)
{
    echo $a . ' = ' . $b . '<BR>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this question is super old but here is another example. Sometimes localhost IP is just ::1

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] === "127.0.0.1"  || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] === "::1")
{
     echo 'I am using localhost enviroment';
}
```